# Why Calculated column inside power app show zeros inside the decimal points

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have the following calculated field inside SharePoint:-

[image]

but inside power app canvas i will get a lot of zero (for example 32.000000000000) inside the field, i tried the below formula but it did not remove the zeros:-

[image]

any advice how i can show maximum of 2 decimal points as the field is of type currency for USD..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Parent.Default is possibly considered a *Text* data type.
Can you please try wrapping it in `Value()` and see if that helps?

```
Text(Value(Parent.Default),"[$-en-US]$#,###.00", "en-US")
```